# The distribution on the number line of the sum of squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $x,y,z$ are all non-negative integers, then what is the density of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ on the number line near $N$?

From the plot it seems pretty much linear, i.e. $dn/dN=C$ where $C$ is some constant whose numerical value is about $0.833\simeq 1-1/6$, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [Legendre Three Squares Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) Any number not of the form $4^e(8k+7)$ is a sum of three squares. And the ones of that shape cannot be.

If $N$ is very large, about $\frac{N}{8}$ of the numbers from $1$ to $N$ are of the shape $8k+7$, about $\frac{N}{4\cdot8}$ are of the form $4(8k+7)$, and so on. So for large $N$ the approximate proportion of the numbers from $1$ to $N$ not representable as a sum of three squares is 
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\cdots\right).$$ 
The sum above is $\frac{1}{6}$.